# Triage audit question about typo and off topic blindly takes upvotes as metric?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits

Triage review question:

[What is the Java equivalent of __builtin_clz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185482/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-builtin-clz)

> I need a Java equivalent of `__builtin_clz`.
> It feels like the answer should be `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros` but they return completely different answers.
> I'm starting to wonder if there is a low-level reason for this - maybe endianness? or some quirk of unsigned?
>
> EDIT: False alarm. This is purely caused by a typo - the original code actually calls `__builtin_ctzll` and is matched by `Long.numberOfTrailingZeros`

This post has 5 upvotes.

As the OP states in his own question via edit, his whole post is based on a misunderstanding / typo. He even tries to stop incoming answers by answering his own question with the clear hint.

Unless I am totally blind to the big picture, my understanding of this post is that it's a general typo-in-question problem.

I followed the recommended guideline of flagging it with off topic / likely not useful to others.

Suddenly the system jumps in my face with the standard: STOP! Look and Listen. This was an audit... This post is obviously supreme quality.

My guess is, that the system blindly takes the upvotes as a quality measurement of the content of a question and then queues those as possible candidates for audits.
This is obviously problematic. Upvotes sometimes reflect honoring honesty, general wording or dozens of other things but not necessarily purely the quality of the problem-answer metric.

If my hunch is correct this definitely has to be addressed as these kind of misunderstandings will increase over time, not alleviate.

Comment: I'd say this is less about taking upvotes as a quality measurement, and more about the review audits' bad choice of questions. This is why no matter how hard I try, I always end up getting review banned...

Comment: The "EDIT..." should just be edited out of the Question. They've put that same in an Answer on the post.

Comment: I don't agree with the dupe but that was just meta commentary in my opinion. So I edited it out.